# maven version command with java home

Tags: java, maven

**Correct example taken from Apache webside**

> Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe;
> 2018-06-17T20:33:14+02:00) Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.5.4
> **Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre**
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
> version: "10.8.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

**An incorrect result I am getting in Command Prompt Windows 10**

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>mvn -v
```

> Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe;
> 2018-06-17T11:33:14-07:00) Maven home:
> C:\new_software\apache-maven-3.5.4-bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin..
> **Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre** Default locale: en_US,
> platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0",
> arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

**I set up System Variables in Environment Variables**

> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
>
> M2_HOME C:\new_software\apache-maven-3.5.4-bin\apache-maven-3.5.4

**Added to the Path in System Variables**

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin
>
> %M2_HOME%\bin

What could be the reason for getting

> runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre

instead

> Java home:
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Comment: `Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` is for Mac-osx and not for windows, I think you might have downloaded mac-osx package of maven.

Comment: hope this: https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10 and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm will help

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason

> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181